# How can I tell what version of Windows Remote Desktop Protocol that I have installed?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remotefx

My eventual goal is to use RemoteFX, which I understand is in RDP8. However, I may already have RDP8. How can I tell which version of Remote Desktop Protocol I'm using?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736828(v=ws.10).aspx) is a Microsoft Technet article explaining how to check the version of the remote desktop client.

By default in Windows 7 you will have RDP 7, but you can update it to RDP 8.1 by following [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2923545/en) from Microsoft support.

Comment: Actual update here:
https://support.microsoft.com/KB/2830477